# Flex 3 RichTextEditor HTML uses deprecated tags

Tags: html, apache-flex, flex3, rich-text-editor

I'm working on a project that has an administrative web application written in Flex 3, and a public website built using PHP. There is one section of the administrative app where administrators can write documents to display on the public website. The app uses a RichTextEditor component to let the administrators do this.

The problem comes when the html text generated by the RichTextEditor is displayed on the website. It properly displayed the text with the correct color, alignment, etc, but the size of the text is inccorect. It displays all the text at the same size, and it's huge.

Being new to Flex, I looked to see what kind of HTML it was generating. It uses the  tag extensively, which I've discovered is deprecated/unreliable/everyone recommends not using it.

So my question is this: Does anyone know of a way that I can somehow tell flex to use style attributes on a span or div rather than using the font tag in the HTML that it generates?

If not, do you know of an existing tool of some kind that will convert font tags to a better format? I haven't been able to find a solution to either of these yet, but I'll keep looking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found the following, might be worth checking out.

[Flex mx:RichTextEditor to HTML](http://cesaric.com/?p=10)